# How to change input text direction from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I reverse text in HTML?
If I write "apple" I want to change it to "elppa".
Here is what I have tried. But it only changes the text direction!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate text container

CSS

```
.text-rotated {
   transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

Or another way in JS

```
var p = document.querySelector('p');

var reversed = p.innerText.split('').reverse().join('');

p.innerText = reversed;
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/0w0te0nz/)  JSFiddle

Comment: Its should be applied to block container I think, example https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/8xm3hu0e/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `javascript` for it like this

```js
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}

var rstring = reverseString("apple");
console.log(rstring)
```

or you can do it in html like this

```html
<p>
  &#x202e; apple
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

if you want to use for every input attribute in your page.

```
.input {
  text-align:right;
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
}
```

OR

If you want to affect one input.

```html
First name: <input type="text" style="text-align:right;unicode-bidi:bidi-override; direction:rtl;"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Taken from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/reversing-text/)

```css
.rtl {
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<div>apple</div>
<div class="rtl">apple</div>
```